# PayPal Express Checkout - Sale vs. Payment

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm finding the PayPal dev docs confusing, to say the least. Express Checkout has 3 different actions:

```
Authorization
Order
Sale
```

Using the client-side api, I've set up a simple `sale` of a single item. Now I want to verify, server-side, that this sale has fully completed; the Express Checkout docs say I should use an API call to `payment` to do so (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/show-payment-details/)

Why would I not use an API call to `sale`, or is that an option too? What is the difference between a `sale` and a `payment` in this example? When a buyer purchases my single item, is there both a `sale` and a  `payment` that I can query?

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#sale_get

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`payment` is the parent object of `sale`, `authorization` and `order`, which means whenever you create a payment intent (either it's a `sale`, `authorization` or `order`), you can get the details via the parent `payment_id`.

That said, the reason why in this step **[Show payment details to buyer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/show-payment-details/)** you would rather call `/v1/payments/payment/{payment_id}` instead of  `/v1/payments/sale/{sale_id}` is that, at this point you've not [executed the payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/execute-payments/) and you won't see a `sale_id` until then in the API response.
(*so this step is just for showing the payment details in the page before your buyer clicking Place Order and you executing the payment*).

In other cases, say if you have already executed the payment and have a `sale_id` from the response, you can definitely verify that by making a GET call to `/v1/payments/sale/{sale_id}`, though there're other ways for you to get the payment details async from PayPal via [webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/rest-webhooks/?mark=webhook) or [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/?mark=ipn).

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful to clear things up. One question about the payment/ endpoint though, created a new question here if you want to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49411807/paypal-rest-get-payment-details-only-works-for-payments-that-have-yet-to-comp

Comment: It looks like v2 API has totally redesigned, it's always about order: all chargings start from `order create`, then `approve by user throw browser`, then `capture` or `authorize`. PayPal always makes things confusing while can't describe it clearly. Well there are still something about the principle `Payment` but looks like just something about `authorization` the `Order`